# Custom Cursor, can't click on DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to make a circle that is following mouse, aka custom cursor. In fact it's working as expected. But i have one issue. If there is a for example button, under the circle, and i want to click the button through the circle it doesn't work. *I can click on element and it works fine, only when the circle is not under mouse yet.

Played with z-index and other thing, but there was no proper result, because i want to have that circle visible over hovered element, like it is in the example down below.

```js
window.CustomCursor = new(function() {
 const self = this;
 const css = `
  .customCursor {
   z-index: 999;
   width: 22px;
   height: 22px;
   border: 1.2px solid #2980b9;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   transition-duration: 200ms;
   transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
 `;
 //Creating Style
 const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(style);

 //Creating Cursor
 const cursor = document.createElement('div');
 cursor.className = "customCursor";
 document.querySelector('body').appendChild(cursor);


 //Creating Logic
 document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  const {pageX, pageY} = e;
  cursor.setAttribute(`style`, `top: ${pageY - 11}px; left: ${pageX - 11}px;`);
 });

 document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  //soon
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #0f1215;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alert('Hi')">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to the cursor styles.

```
const css = `
    .customCursor {
        z-index: 999;
        width: 22px;
        height: 22px;
        border: 1.2px solid #2980b9;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        transition-duration: 200ms;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        pointer-events: none; /* ADD_ME */
    }
`;
```

Comment: So simple. And i was struggling for over 3 hours with it. : | Thanks buddy!